# BeautifulSoup: print(s.find_all(class="title")) SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: python

Script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

content = '<p class="title">hello world</p>'

s = bs(content)
print(s.find_all(class="title"))
```

Output:

```
  File "bs.py", line 7
    print(s.find_all(class="title"))
                         ^
  SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

BS Docs:

```
soup.find_all(id="link2")
# [<a class="sister" href="http://example.com/lacie" id="link2">Lacie</a>]
```

Question:
Why is there a syntax error?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`class` is a keyword in python. Use `find_all('p', { 'class' : "title"})` or `find_all(class_="title")` instead.

Comment: Just replace `class` with `class_`.